# JLabel in front of JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jsplitpane

My goal is to have a window with 2 panels in different colors in the background. They each cover a specific percentage of the screen and this changes periodically. I did this by creating a `JSplitPane`. But now I want to add a `JLabel` showing some data in front of all of this in the middle of the screen. How would I do this?

Comment: You need a panel with components or just to paint the background with different colors?

Comment: @czdepski just paint the background with different colors, but the location of the divider between them has to change constantly

Comment: Change with user interaction? I ask because is possible to just paint the background (without JSplitPane) and then you can put components over it, use something like a layered pane or absolute positioning components, all depends on your needs.

Comment: @czdepski no, it does not have to change with user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your description, I prefer using a `paintComponent` approach. You just paint 2 rectangles on the background of components and still positioning components as usual, as simple as this:

```
  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
  f.pack();
  f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()) {
     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int perc = (int)((float)getWidth()*0.3f); // set % to fill
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, perc, g.getClipBounds().height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(perc, 0, getWidth()-perc, getHeight());
     }

  };
  f.add(p);
  p.add(new JButton("test"));
  f.setVisible(true);
```

My example does it on a `JPanel` but it can be done directly on `JFrame` and then puts a `JButton` over it using a `FlowLayout`. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, haven't thought of this approach!

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `JLayer`: [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Other Swing Features)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class JLayerTest {
  public Component makeUI() {
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setResizeWeight(.4);
    splitPane.setLeftComponent(makeLabel(Color.RED));
    splitPane.setRightComponent(makeLabel(Color.GREEN));
    //splitPane.setEnabled(false);
    //splitPane.setDividerSize(0);

    JPanel rubberStamp = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = makeLabel(Color.BLUE);
    label.setText("JLabel");
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 50));
    LayerUI<JSplitPane> layerUI = new LayerUI<JSplitPane>() {
      @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);
        Dimension d = label.getPreferredSize();
        int x = (c.getWidth()  - d.width) / 2;
        int y = (c.getHeight() - d.height) / 2;
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, label, rubberStamp, x, y, d.width, d.height);
      }
    };
    return new JLayer<>(splitPane, layerUI);
  }
  public static JLabel makeLabel(Color color) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(color);
    return label;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JLayerTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, looks pretty complicated but seems to work :)